# Retrive data from website to salesforce.com

Tags: webservices, community

I need to get the details of an 'X' user from xyz website .Please help me with the idea in making it successful using salesforce.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, in order to gather a bit more interest in your question you need to provide a bit more details on what you have look at so far? For example the developer.force.com site, the Salesforce REST API documentation is also a good place.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use Web Services to display that user details.

Comment: Would you mind adding some more detail as to why webservices are a good choice, and maybe what considerations or assumptions lie within this answer ?

Comment: The usecase is--there is a public website where a new user can create his account for signing into his website ,and each account have few projects ,So I need to access the projects belonging to a particular account using salesforce webservices.Could you please help me to achieve this as im new to both webservices as well as salesforce.

Comment: to get the user info from xyz website we need a good handshake between salesforce and xyz website .as every website provides some web services ,such that if you want some information from xyz website they'll ask you to send parameters and syntax as per their documents .so none of the standard feature in salesforce support this ,so my best way is go for webservices,use may use REST ,SOAP ,or WSDL